# Bubbling up a button command in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have a button in a user control called LauncherView + LauncherViewModel, I add this to the main window called MainView + MainViewModel.

When I click on the button I would like to capture the event in the MainViewModel. How can I do this?

In the LauncherViewModel is easy enough with:

```
RelayCommand launchCommand;

public ICommand LaunchCommand{
    get{
        if (launchCommand == null){
            launchCommand = new RelayCommand(LaunchCommandExecute, CanLaunchCommandExecute);
        }
        return launchCommand;
    }
}

private void LaunchCommandExecute(object parameter){
    //Do something to recognize the button.
    //Could use ObservableCollection<Module> module_objects
    //to match, if I could get the buttons content or name
}

private bool CanLaunchCommandExecute(object parameter){
    return true;
}
```

However tried this in the MainViewModel as well hoping for a bubbling effect to occur, no such luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a [`RoutedCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `RelayCommand`.

Alternatively, your `ViewModel` could raise an event, to which the parent (`MainViewModel`) could subscribe.  When the button is pressed, you could simply raise the event.

Comment: I stuck the above RelayCommand into the MainViewModel, then in the XAML I changed the button Command to: Command="{Binding LaunchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}". It works but is this ok? I suppose it is, however when I get to views inside views your approach would suit it better.

Comment: Could you send through an example of how to code this RoutedCommand please? I am having a little trouble finding what I think is a workable solution on the net.

Comment: Correction to above: Command="{Binding DataContext.LaunchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"

Comment: @Hank RoutedCommand and routing in general is far too long for a SO comment... but it's designed to specifically allow WPF's routing frameworks to handle things properly.  Read up on the link above, and you'll see lots of links showing how it works, so you can see how to route the command through the entire View infrastructure, including optionally handling or passing through, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change LaunchCommand to a dependency property and then bind that to your MainWindow's command in the XAML where you declare the LauncherView.

Comment: This is probably going to be a bit tricky. The Launcher is a separate assembly and loaded dynamically. a = Assembly.Load(assembly); etc